# How to use @Conditional with Mapstruct

Tags: spring-boot, mapstruct

I want to use Spring Boot @Conditional with Mapstruct.

I want to restrict the creation of spring beans using property file.
I am using @Conditional for the same.

How can I implement it for mapstruct beans?

Comment: Could you please share your attempt?

Comment: I could not find any approaches. Tried googling and found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Configuration class with conditional beans:

```
@Configuration
class ConditionalBeanConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @Conditional... <--
  ConditionalBean conditionalBean(){
    return new ConditionalBean();
  };

}
```

so It could look like:

```
@Configuration
class MapperBeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "my.property.enabled", havingValue = "true")
    public MyMapper myMapperImplV1() {
        return new MyMapperImplV1();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "my.property.enabled", havingValue = "false", matchIfMissing = true)
    public MyMapper myMapperImplV2() {
        return new MyMapperImplV2();
    }

}
```

you can learn more on this medium article: [working with springs conditional annotation for conditional bean registration](https://medium.com/@AlexanderObregon/working-with-springs-conditional-annotation-for-conditional-bean-registration-f65bc6a486ea)

Comment: Thanks Paul. I did not think of this method. I was trying to figure out how to create a mapper with componentModel = "spring". Thanks for the support.