# Mapstruct spring @ConditionalOnProperty @Conditional

Tags: spring, mapstruct

I have an interface **EntityMapper** and several other interfaces that extend it, like **EntityAMapper**, **EntityBMapper**, **EntityCMapper**, etc. Each sub-interface is annotate with
`@Mapper(config = EntityMapperConfig.class)` and `@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "propKey", havingValue = "propValue")`, where **EntityMapperConfig** is:

```
@MapperConfig(componentModel = SPRING, mappingInheritanceStrategy = AUTO_INHERIT_FROM_CONFIG)
public interface EntityMapperConfig {
}
```

`propValue` has a unique value for each type **EntityAMapper**, **EntityBMapper**, **EntityCMapper**, etc.

I need that at most one (and only one) bean implementing interface EntityMapper is present in Spring context: depending on the value of propKey, its type wil be **EntityAMapper** or **EntityBMapper** or **EntityCMapper** etc.

How to achieve this?
Is it possible to make Mapstruct annotate each sub-class implementation (**EntityAMapperImpl**, **EntityAMapperImpl**, **EntityAMapperImpl**, etc...) with @ConditionalOnProperty?

Thanx for helping!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use @Conditional with Mapstruct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77662493/how-to-use-conditional-with-mapstruct)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from MapStruct 1.6.0.Beta1 there is a new annotation `@AnnotateWith` which allows you to pass annotations to the generated code.

In your case you can do something like:

```java
@Mapper(config = EntityMapperConfig.class)
@AnnotateWith(value = ConditionalOnProperty.class, elements = [
    @AnnotateWith.Element(name = "value", strings = "propKey"),
    @AnnotateWith.Element(name = "havingValue", strings = "propAValue")
]}
public interface EntityAMapper extends EntityMapper {

}

@Mapper(config = EntityMapperConfig.class)
@AnnotateWith(value = ConditionalOnProperty.class, elements = [
    @AnnotateWith.Element(name = "value", strings = "propKey"),
    @AnnotateWith.Element(name = "havingValue", strings = "propBValue")
]}
public interface EntityBMapper extends EntityMapper {

}

@Mapper(config = EntityMapperConfig.class)
@AnnotateWith(value = ConditionalOnProperty.class, elements = [
    @AnnotateWith.Element(name = "value", strings = "propKey"),
    @AnnotateWith.Element(name = "havingValue", strings = "propCValue")
]}
public interface EntityCMapper extends EntityMapper {

}
```

This would then generate code like:

```java
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "propKey", havingValue = "propAValue")
public class EntityAMapperImpl implements EntityAMapper {

}

@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "propKey", havingValue = "propBValue")
public class EntityBMapperImpl implements EntityBMapper {

}

@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "propKey", havingValue = "propCValue")
public class EntityCMapperImpl implements EntityCMapper {

}
```